# Get pointer value via reflection

Tags: c#, pointers, reflection

I have an instance of the type `object`, from which I know that it is a pointer (can easily be verified with `myobject.GetType().IsPointer`). Is it possible to obtain the pointer's value via reflection?

code so far:

```
object obj = .... ; // type and value unknown at compile time
Type t = obj.GetType();

if (t.IsPointer)
{
    void* ptr = Pointer.Unbox(obj);

    // I can obtain its (the object's) bytes with:
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(t)];
    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)ptr, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // but how can I get the value represented by the byte array 'buffer'?
    // or how can I get the value of *ptr?
    // the following line obviously doesn't work:
    object val = (object)*ptr; // error CS0242 (obviously)
}
```

---

**Addendum №1:** As the object in question is value type *-not a reference type-*, I cannot use [`GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.fromintptr(v=vs.110).aspx) followed by [`GCHandle::Target`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.target(v=vs.110).aspx) to obtain the object's value...

Comment: FromIntPtr expects a GC handle. It cannot work with pointers at all. Just pointing this out.

Comment: `I can obtain its bytes with:` This does not obtain the pointers bytes. It obtains 4 or 8 bytes from the memory location pointed to by obj. What do you mean by "the pointers value"? It's `ptr`!

Comment: @usr: regarding your first comment: I know that, that is the reason why I said, that it will not work, _because_ it is a value type. regarding your second comment: I obtain the value's bytes - not the pointer's ones.

Comment: and what do I mean with the pointer's value? I mean `*ptr`, meaning the value of the object stored at the address, to which `ptr` is pointing ;)

Comment: GCHandle would not work even if it was a ref type. A GCHandle is different from a pointer to an object. You can't obtain a handle from a pointer.; Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx work? You need to determine the struct type from the pointer type. I assume that is possible.

Comment: `PtrToStructure` is a good call - I will take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose what you need is PtrToStructure. Something like this:

```
if (t.IsPointer) {
    var ptr = Pointer.Unbox(obj);

    // The following line was edited by the OP ;)
    var underlyingType = t.GetElementType();
    var value = Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)ptr, underlyingType); 
}
```

Comment: Well I left an exuse in comment, so maybe programmer's god will forgive me :) Do you know of a reliable way to get underlying type from pointer type?

Comment: @Evk: Thank you very much, Sir :) I also edited your fourth code line ;)

Comment: Yes thank you too for saying how to get type from pointer type.

Comment: Calling the pointer base type an "element type" is kind of a hack. I did not see that API. LINQpad did not show any helpful properties.